# Donde encuentro la fucnión SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, derby

Intento convertir una base de datos existente para usar autenticación NATIVA. El manual del desarrollador de Derby dice que la creación de un usuario lo convertirá.

```
    CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('app', 'app');
```

Part of my code:

```
    String sql = "call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER( 'app', 'app' )";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Me sale una excepción que dice que no reconoce la funcion "create_user. Y  veo que no viene en el folder de "SYSC UTIL". Debería estar ahí? o que otro error se me está pasando?

El folder de "SYSC UTIL" lo veo en Netbeans, que lo que uso para programar. Y tengo la base de datos como un servicio.

**Obtengo la siguiente excepción :**

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER' no se reconoce como una función o procedimiento.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at Database.main(Database.java:141)
>   Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER' no se reconoce como una función o procedimiento.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepare_(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
>       ... 2 more

Comment: pon tu pregunta en español para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: hago otra pregunta o solo edito esta?

Comment: no solo edita la pregunta para que este en español

Answer (score -1):

Bueno. Ya lo resolví. Había bajado una versión de Derby, y era actualizada, y suponía que es la que se estaba referenciando por Netbeans.

Me metí a Netbeans, en "Servicios>Database>JabaDB" y luego propiedades, y me di cuenta que estaba referenciando una versión de Derby que tenía el JDK y de hecho era un JDK antiguo. Entonces cambié esa propiedad a un JDK actualizado, el JDK8, que también tenía una versión de Derby más actualizada que la que yo había bajado.

Eso solucionó el problema.

Había 3 diferentes versiones de Derby en mi sistema y ni sabía. Solo configuré Netbeans para que usara la versión más reciente.

Saludos.